# Python -- find tar.gz file of specific pattern only in target folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a list, containing paths as its elements - few elements are genuine paths and rests are dummy values.

My requirement is to get the tar.gz file of certain format, under the target folder alone(not recursively) of the genuine path elements.

```
path_elements = ['/home/work/checkouts/repos/chinos', '/home/work/checkouts/repos/walmart', '/home/work/checkouts/repos/players', '/home/work/checkouts/repos/k7', '/home/work/checkouts/repos/distributor', '/home/work/checkouts/repos/matlab']

 for dir in path_elements:
    target_dir = dir+'/'+'target'
    target_file = ".*-[0-9].[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6,7}.tar.gz"

    if os.path.isdir(target_dir) and glob.glob(target_folder+'/'+target_file):
        print("Tar.gz of expected format is available under the"+ target_dir)
```

Example:

`/home/work/checkouts/repos/chinos/target/4.14.440.4569874.tar.gz`, I tried both `os.path.isfile` with wildcards and `glob` with wildcards, no luck though.

Hope, I've explained myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using glob incorrectly. As mentioned in some [references](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/):

> The pattern rules for glob are not regular expressions.

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to find the `.tar.gz` files and then [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) to match the naming format you need.

```
import glob
import os
import re

path_elements = [
    '/home/work/checkouts/repos/chinos',  # Dummy path
    '/home/nponcian/Documents/',  # Genuine path. .tar.gz file exists in correct name format.
    '/home/nponcian/Documents/3/',  # Genuine path. .tar.gz file doesn't exist.
    '/home/nponcian/Documents/2/',  # Genuine path. .tar.gz file exists in correct name format.
    '/home/work/checkouts/repos/distributor',  # Dummy path
    '/home/nponcian/Documents/1/',  # Genuine path. .tar.gz file exists but in incorrect name format.
]

for path_dir in path_elements:
    target_file_ext = os.path.join(path_dir, 'target', '*.tar.gz')
    re_file = r".*-[0-9].[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6,7}.tar.gz"

    tar_gz_files = glob.glob(target_file_ext)
    print(path_dir, tar_gz_files)

    for file in tar_gz_files:
        match = re.match(re_file, os.path.basename(file))
        print("\t", match)
```

```
$ python3 script.py 
/home/work/checkouts/repos/chinos []
/home/nponcian/Documents/ ['/home/nponcian/Documents/target/any-0.0.123-123456.tar.gz']
     <re.Match object; span=(0, 25), match='any-0.0.123-123456.tar.gz'>
/home/nponcian/Documents/3/ []
/home/nponcian/Documents/2/ ['/home/nponcian/Documents/2/target/any-9.8.765-009988.tar.gz']
     <re.Match object; span=(0, 25), match='any-9.8.765-009988.tar.gz'>
/home/work/checkouts/repos/distributor []
/home/nponcian/Documents/1/ ['/home/nponcian/Documents/1/target/any-123.tar.gz']
     None
```

Comment: Thank you.. Appreciate the explanation as well !
In case, if I wanted to capture the genuine paths having the tar.gz into a dictionary, is it possible still ?

Comment: You mean you wanted to list all those paths with a valid `.tar.gz`? Yes you can. In the inner `for` loop of my answer just add `if match: my_list.append(path_dir)` or `if match: my_list.append(match.string)`.